# Jquery fade in/out on scroll only happens once

Tags: jquery

New to the community and new to programming.

Here is what I am trying to do, I want to have an image fade in when you scroll down to 1000 on a webpage, then fade out when you scroll back up. This part of it works just fine. But only once! The problem is that I can't get it to execute multiple times. What am I missing to allow this to repeat whenever you scroll up and down?

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) { 
    $("#logo2").fadeIn();
    checkOffset(); 
  } else {
    $("#logo2").stop().fadeOut();
  }
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What's in your `checkOffset();`-function? [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32eckm71/) works just fine

Comment: Nothing, that was an error and I removed it. It works perfectly in the fiddle you provided, but when I use the snippet of code on my page, it still only works once.

Comment: I must have conflicting code somewhere in my page because when I remove everything but what you have in the fiddle, it works...

Comment: Without some more code I won't be able to help you man...

Comment: This fiddle: ( https://jsfiddle.net/32eckm71/34/ ) has my code. The idea is to get the yellow box (logo2) to fade in at a certain point and then fade back out when you scroll back up. Basically the exact OPPOSITE of what (logo) is doing.

Comment: How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/zubn7dut/1/

Comment: Here is a much much cleaner version of that fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32eckm71/37/
(Bundled added css-styles, 3x "window.scroll"-functions are unnecessary, one is enough)

Comment: Please include all of the code in the question itself. You can use the Stack Snippets button (looks like a page with angle brackets on it) to produce the same experience as in the jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll take note of the requirements for posting in the future. Still getting the hang of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `animate` with `opacity`.

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var logo = $("#logo2");

  logo.clearQueue();
  logo.stop();

  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1000) { 
    logo.animate({opacity: 1}, 400);
  } else {
    logo.animate({opacity: 0}, 400);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/32eckm71/35/

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you so much!

I'm still learning all the different functions and tricks so I appreciate you introducing me to something new I can play with.